# PostgreSQL: transpose multiple date columns dynamically to rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, postgres-crosstab

My apologies if this has been asked before. I've searched the Postgres manual and many SO answers and still can't find a solution. I'm struggling to find the right SQL (postgres) command to convert the following table:

```
| client | starts_on  | ends_on    |
|--------|------------|------------|
| ACME   | 2019-12-01 | 2020-02-28 |
```

into the desired output:

```
| client | year       | month      |
|--------|------------|------------|
| ACME   | 2019       | 12         |
| ACME   | 2020       | 1          |
| ACME   | 2020       | 2          |
```

Should this be done with `crosstab`? If so, how can I use the `date_trunc` function?

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    crosstab ('SELECT client, date_trunc(' year ', ends_on), date_trunc(' month ', ends_on)
         FROM example_table') 
AS ct ("Client" text,
        "Year" int,
        "Month" int);
```

This throws the following error:

> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "month"
>   LINE 4:  crosstab ('SELECT client, date_trunc('month', ends_on), dat...

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It is just the quoting. Simplest solution is to use dollar-quoting for your query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a pivoting/cross tab problem.  You need to generate rows for all the months between the two dates.  Use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.client, extract(year from gs.dte), extract(month from gs.dte)
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.starts_on, t.ends_on, interval '1 month') gs(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d5c0600fa76341ec7cb86c71369e676) is a db<>fidle.

Answer (score 0):

Though the original question appears to be a semantic problem, the *quoting of strings containing quotes* might be useful for future readers:

---

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
        ( client text
        , ends_on timestamp
        );

SELECT *
FROM public.crosstab (
$qq$
SELECT client, date_trunc('year', ends_on), date_trunc('month', ends_on)
         FROM example_table
$qq$
) AS ct ("Client" text, "Year" int, "Month" int);
```